# Custom SplitContainer

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, splitcontainer

I'm using standart SplitContainer - very useful thing, but sincerely it looks a little ugly. I took a look through other kind of SplitContainer implementation for ex. [FireFox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiLNm.png).

Could You tell me - how to custom draw the Split bar in order to look a little nicer or at least how's in FF?

Answer (score 2):

**The Easy Solution:**

Change the `System.Windows.Forms.SplitContainer.BorderStyle` to `Fixed3D`. The `Splitter` will look like the same you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I took my time and made some. [Here](http://pastebin.com/wu5du0Dd) is the code of my custom SplitContainer.

But there is a little bug - when SplitContainer is focused and a key is pressed - drawing disappear - I know that this should be fixed by calling Invalidate method - but I'm call it in KeyPressed, KeyDown, KeyUp - no result. Could You tell me which event I should check to fix that bug?

Comment: Solved!!! just needed to call Invalidate in some key press events. Paste code updated [here](http://pastebin.com/XWQ0RYP7)

Comment: Thank you for this, and @DreadAngel's updated copy. 10 years later, I find it useful and I plan to add dots in place of the inner line. Nice control!